# Connecting to mysql periodically causes php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, mysqli, dns

So I make many websites and have previously had no issue using MSQL. However I recently reset my VPS so it got re-installed. I usually connect to my database using a domain. This domain has it's dns configured with colouflare and I have never had any issues with it before.

However, now, I would probably say once in every 5 times a website loads and it connects to the database using PHP, it fails to connect.

This is the error it gets:
`Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for db.domain.com failed: Name does not resolve in /home/container/webroot/private/database.php on line 17

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for db.domain.com failed: Name does not resolve in /home/container/webroot/private/database.php:17 Stack trace: #0 /home/container/webroot/private/database.php(17): mysqli_connect() #1 /home/container/webroot/website/dashboard/site/payments/index.php(5): connectToDatabase() #2 {main} thrown in /home/container/webroot/private/database.php on line 17`
```

I then refresh and it's gone, the domain is pointing to the correct ip adress, but the thing I don't understand is that when I just use the ip adress rather than the domain, then I get no issue. The only reason I don't just use the ip over the domain is that, not sure if this is a common thing, using the ip is painfully slow compared to using a domain.

This is the code in database.php, but I also get the issue when using wordperss so it is most likely not to do with the database.php file.

```
<?php
function connectToDatabase() {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); // This is just here to get the error
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $servername = "db.domain.com:3306";
    $username = "u1_Xm0swdMrNR";
    $password = ""; // Set obviously
    $dbname = ""; // Set obviously

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    return $conn;
}
?>
```

The only difference between this time and before is the fact I am using a reverse proxy, but that is not set to use the domain db.domain.com, so I can't think why that would be the issue. Not to mention my friend uses the exact same nginx reverse proxy config as me and does not have an issue using a domain to connect to the db.

I should also mention that I run all my sites in docker containers, but mysql on the host machine.

All help appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:
So I made a test script just so I can visualize it. I took the script on my server in the docker container. it of course gives an error, after around 4 pings to MySQL. I stick on my server outside of docker and it works with no issues. It does 100 pings in about a second and no errors. Then I disable my reverse proxy and still does not work, so it's not that. I think stick my script on a completely different server and run it. I wait for it to load, it takes a fairly long time, but it manages to do 100 pings, no errors, connecting through the domain. I next try running the script through docker on the other vps, and what do you know, it works. So something to do with the panel connecting to the db. THe db is on the host machine so I am more than confused. I wrote some nodejs code and ran it on docker, and that had no issues connecting to the DB, and it kept pinging it without any troubles.

Comment: Without PHP, try connecting from console (ssh) with above credentials. Or use some DB application( ex: Navicat)

Comment: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for db.domain.com failed: Name does not resolve` - Sounds like a DNS issue. It can be your server that has some issue with the DNS it's using for the lookup, your Cloudflare DNS. It's most likely nothing to do with PHP specifically so you need to do more investigation and try to find where the lookup fails.